# How can I set which drive mysql uses for temporary tables?

Tags: mysql, linux

I'm running this query on a 16 GB table:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
```

After some wait, it ends with this error:

```
#1114 - The table '#sql-491_cebd' is full.
```

Just before it does, Linux Mint 19 reports that the disk almost full, and I see it filling up in disk manager (though there's still 8 GB left when it fails, so not sure what's happening there).  It's impossible to free up more room on this disk, so I need to move the operation to another drive.

How can I make mysql do that?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/internal-temporary-tables.html "Temporary files are created in the directory defined by the `tmpdir` variable." And https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_tmpdir "`innodb_tmpdir` Used to define an alternate directory for temporary sort files created during online ALTER TABLE operations that rebuild the table." The former is global only, the latter can be global or session.

Comment: Thanks, that looks like the thing, but it causes my mysql to fail to restart.  I'll have to make a new question about that.